# Java 2D programming: Rendering techniques

Tags: java, swing, rendering

I have been programming in java for a while now and I've just now started 2D graphics(game development). While coding my game, I have noticed rendering issues with my game. While my player is running around the screen, the pixels will glitch around. It's like lag on a multiplayer game, but its barely noticeable. After researching this issue I have not come up with any solutions, so I'm asking for your help.

MY QUESTION: I am experiencing poor rendering in my game and I'm wondering if my way of rendering is poor. If so, Can you point me to any resources?

MY RENDERING CLASS

```
public class Render extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    int SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    Game game;
    Thread t;

    public Render(int w,int h,Game g){
        this.SCREEN_WIDTH = w;
        this.SCREEN_HEIGHT = h;
        this.game = g;
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);

    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.translate(-this.game.getCamera().getX(), -game.getCamera().getY());


        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        //fill the screen with black
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, game.getLevelHandler().getLevel().getWidth() * 32, game.getLevelHandler().getLevel().getHeight() * 32);

        /**for(Entity E: game.getObjects()){
            E.draw(g2d);
        }*/
        //send the graphics object to my player...IS THIS OKAY TO DO?
        game.getPlayer().draw(g2d);

    }

    public void start(){
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

}




public class Player extends Entity{
    float dx,dy,moveSpeed;
    boolean jumping, canJump;

    float terminalVelocity,acceleration = 0;
    int GravityCounter,jumps,maxJumps,jumpheight = 0;


    public Player(float x, float y, float w, float h, ObjectID id, Game g) {
        super(x, y, w, h, id, g);
        //gravity
        terminalVelocity += 7;
        acceleration += 0.2;
        moveSpeed += 2.5;

        //jumping
        jumpheight = 40;        
        maxJumps = 2;
        jumps = maxJumps;
    }

    public void tick() {
        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;

        collisions();
        move();

        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }

    public void collisions(){
    }

        public void move(){
        }
        //the drawing
        public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawRect((int)x, (int)y, (int)w, (int)h);
        }

    }
```

EDIT: downloadable link [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzJiTlGQ0HoFZENGa1ZVX0wzcGs/view?usp=sharing)
, If any changes are needed, I'll try and correct it. Also, does this glitching happen when there is a memory leak?

I revised my code because of suggestions, This is what I have now.

RENDERER:

```
public class Render extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    int SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    Game game;
    Thread t;

    public Render(int w,int h,Game g){
        this.SCREEN_WIDTH = w;
        this.SCREEN_HEIGHT = h;
        this.game = g;
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);

    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(16);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.translate(-this.game.getCamera().getX(), -game.getCamera().getY());


        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, game.getLevelHandler().getLevel().getWidth() * 32,                 game.getLevelHandler().getLevel().getHeight() * 32);

        for(Entity E: game.getObjects()){
            synchronized(E){E.draw(g2d);}
        }

        synchronized(game.getPlayer()){game.getPlayer().draw(g2d);}

     }

    public void start(){
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

}
```

The player class did not change

Source Code: [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzJiTlGQ0HoFemZIamhlazhhNkE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You've overridden `paint`, but are calling `super.paintComponent`, there's a start of a problem. Remember, Swing is not thread safe, you will need to take measures to synchronise the thread updates with the screen updates to ensure you're not modifying the state of the game entities while they are been painted...

Comment: `while(true) { repaint(); }`...I think you might want to give the EDT some breathing room, try adding `Thread.sleep(16)` after the `repaint`...

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer Look at my revisions above.

Comment: What does this line do for you? `g2d.translate(-this.game.getCamera().getX(), -game.getCamera().getY());`

Comment: Override `paintComponent`, call `super.paintComponent`.  Unless you can provide source code to a runnable example which demonstrates your problem, we aren't going to be able to help further...

Answer (score 0):

I know what's happening here because I was having the exact same problem in the game I'm writing. It sure is a hard thing to find. Your problem is happening because you're rounding your `x` and `y` variables when you draw.

```
g.drawRect((int)x, (int)y, (int)w, (int)h);
```

This is causing your rectangle to jump around a bit. Because it looks like your rectangle can have decimal coordinates, you need to be able to draw the rectangle at decimal coordinates. There's a pretty easy way to do that, but instead let's use a way that will work regardless of what you're drawing.

You're going to need to use some transformations, personally I like [`AffineTransform`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html)'s. There are lots of tutorials about these, but this is the first (non-documentation) result of a google search https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html. I know you're already doing some transformations, but this is what your draw method will look like after you add them.

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        AffineTransform original = g.getTransform(); // keep a copy of the original so that we can restore it
        AffineTransform transform = (AffineTransform)original.clone();
        transform.translate((double)x, (double)y); // translate the transform to the player location, note that x and y can be non-integers here.
        g.transform(transform); // apply the transformation.
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, (int)w, (int)h);
        g.setTransform(original); // restore the original transformation
    }
```

For the rest of your walls and stuff, you can use this exact same method. Remember that the "screen" location of an object is the object's game location minus the camera's game location. Good luck with your game.

Comment: Thanks for responding. But that doesn't seem to fix the issue. I even changed all of my floats to ints, but the glitch is still happening.

Comment: @Nichos You don't have to use ints. You should use `double`'s instead, they have a larger range, and (in my opinion) are easier to work with.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I've come across another issue. I'm translating the screen around my player, and when I add the AffineTransform everything starts to bug out. (sorry for how vague this is, it's hard to explain)

Comment: Also, my "g" object does not recognize gettransform(); (Sorry for the double post)

Comment: @Nichos It is difficult to tell without seeing your code. Could you edit your question and update the code in it?

Comment: I have added the source code. If you import it to (whatever ide) and run it. You will see that the player moves around the screen fine, but sometimes glitches. Then if you go to the player class and remove the commented code(you code) you will see what happens. That is because of the `g.translate` interfering with your code.

Comment: @Nichos Unfortunately my computer can't unzip .rar files, do you have the code in a different format?

Comment: here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzJiTlGQ0HoFU1NWZVlKQmpxMTg&usp=sharing), hopefully google didn't mess with it and it is still importable. If not, you can just add the src files to a new project.